# How to commit a file in SVN through Ant

Tags: svn, ant

Using the [SVN task from tigris](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svn.html) I can't seem to find a way to just commit one file. Is there any way to do this without first having to checkout the folder in SVN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  You cannot check in a single file w/o having a working copy which means you will have to checkout at least one directory.

Perhaps I don't fully understand, but you cannot check in a single file with the svn binaries so you certainly can't do it through ant.

Answer (score 1):

This post has some information about committing a file with checking it out first.
http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2007-06/0937.shtml

Answer (score 0):

If you can also provide WebDAV access to the subversion repository, you could then use curl to upload a single file to the repository without having a working copy.  You won't have a useful commit message, etc., so use with caution.

Answer (score 0):

In svnant you can commit an unversioned file or tree into the repository with `<import/>` task

Comment: That's importing and not committing. If the file is already in SVN it will fail.

Answer (score -2):

put subversion/bin into your PATH
and write own ant task like

```
<macrodef name="svn_call">
  <attribute name="src.path" />
  <attribute name="dst.path" />
  <attribute name="command" />
  <sequential>
    <exec failonerror="true" executable="${env.SVN_HOME}/bin/svn" osfamily="windows">
    <arg line="@{command} @{src.path} @{dst.path}" />
    </exec>
    <exec failonerror="true" executable="${env.SVN_HOME}/bin/svn" osfamily="unix">
    <arg line="@{command} @{src.path} @{dst.path}" />
    </exec>
  </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Comment: The question is how do you commit a file to SVN "without first having to checkout the folder in SVN?"

Comment: sorry, site published first part of my answer only.
full answer is:
1. declare svn_call task
2. for commit one local file into repository use
<svn_call command="import" src.path="${yourFileName}" dst.path="${yourRepositoryUrlRoot}/${yourRepositoryPath}/${yourFileName}"/>

Comment: if you need to update file which already in repository
you can use following commands
<svn_call command="checkout --depth=empty" src.path="${yourRepositoryUrlRoot}/${yourRepositoryPath}" dst.path="${localTempDir}" /> - this checkout oly folder without any files into localTempDir
<svn_call command="update" src.path="${localTempDir}/${yourFileName}" dst.path="" /> - this checkout your file only

update your file any way

<svn_call command="commit -m=''" src.path="${localTempDir}/${yourFileName}" dst.path="" /> - this commit your file only
<delete dir="${localTempDir}" /> - remove temporary files

Comment: for update file which already in repository you need chekout dir contain your file :). but you can checkout your file only without other files from repository.

Comment: also you can first delete your file from repository immediatly
(<svn_call command="delete" src.path="${yourRepositoryUrlRoot}/${yourRepositoryPath}/${yourFileName}" dst.path="" />)
and import new versionof file again
<svn_call command="import" src.path="${yourFileName}" dst.path="${yourRepositoryUrlRoot}/${yourRepositoryPath}/${yourFileName}"/>

Comment: Don't do the delete and import, as delete will also remove file change history, so you won't have change history inbetween versions.